# Typescript Record value type based on Record key

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

Using typescript, I would like to summarize different objects (based on different types) in one single Record while still maintaining type safety / correct IntelliSense.

For this demonstration example, I have the following types:

```
type Level = 'intro' | 'main' | 'outro';

type TypeA = {
    textA: string;
}

type TypeB = {
    textB: string;    
)

type TypeC = {
    textC: string;
)
```

I now would love to have some kind of Record like:

```
const record : Record<level,...> = {
    intro: contains Object of TypeA,
    main: contains Object of TypeB,
    outro: contains Object of TypeC
}
```

later, when i access this object, I would love to get IntelliSense support:

```
record.intro. (should now only suggest textA)
record.main. (should now only suggest textB)
```

I'd like to use a Record in my case because it enforces that I use all type values (intro, main, outro). Is there some way to accomplish this?

Comment: I don't see why you want a `Record` for this at all; objects which require a certain set of keys where each property value type depends on the key are just *interfaces*.  Like, [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WvoVRw) gives you everything I can imagine you want, without trying to force `Record` to be involved. Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer; if not, please [edit] the question to demonstrate an use case that would be unsatisfied by it (and regardless please make sure your code is a [mre] with no typos or pseudocode; I suggest you test it in an IDE first.)

Answer (score 0):

```js
type Level = 'intro' | 'main' | 'outro';

interface LevelRecord {
    intro: TypeA;
    main: TypeB;
    outro: TypeC;
}

const _checkLevelRecord1: Record<Level, unknown> = {} as LevelRecord;
const _checkLevelRecord2: LevelRecord = {} as Record<Level, never>;
```

Comment: I'd like to use it because it enforces me to use all values defined in a type. 
For example, I want to store additional information for each level (intro, main, outro) which are specific to those. If I would add a new level to the level type, I would get a warning that my Record is missing an entry. 
So it ensures that I do not miss anything when things change. 

Given your example, when I add a new level or remove one, your interface would still remain "correct"

Comment: @HaraldSchroeder OK, now I understand you and updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the update! It's almost what I desire. Unfortunately, the type checking is not that perfect compared to the behaviour of a Record. When a key is missing, the Record can refer to those while your solution only indicates that there is something wrong / implicitly missing: "Argument of type boolean is not assignable to parameter of type never". In addition, when creating the interface I'd lose the IntelliSense for the key values, so I'd need to know how my type values are written (a bit picky but still noticeable).  

So I assume there is no way doing so using Records?

Comment: OK, I updated my answer to use Record and provide friendly error messages.

Comment: @HaraldSchroeder Hi, did you see my updated answer?